# Using predicates on a large database?

Tags: marklogic

I have a 50,000,000 document database that I'd like to write to a file the base-uri's for each document.  Running the entire 50,000,000 is too long running (query times out).  So, I thought I'd use predicates to break the database into more manageable batches.  So, I tried the following to get a handle on its performance:

```
for $i in ( 49999000 to 50000000 )
return fn:base-uri( /mainDoc[position()=$i] )
```

But, performance was very slow for these 1000 base uris.  In fact, the query timed out.  I tried a similar query and got similar results (or lack of results):

```
for $i in ( /mainDoc ) [ 49999000 to 50000000 ]
return fn:base-uri( $i )
```

Is there a more performant method of looping through a large database, where documents at the end of the database are equally as quick to obtain as those at the beginning of the database?

Comment: Can you use a URI lexicon? Having access to `cts:uris` would substantially improve performance.

Comment: I tried cts:uris( ( /mainDoc ) [ 49999000 to 50000000 ] ) without any better success.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, that is not the right way to use `cts:uris`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want the document URIs, that easy.  Ensure you have the document lexicon enabled and run a `cts:uris()` call.

To follow your approach to jump ahead in a document list to do something with each document, you can do the work unfiltered to make it fast:

```
for $item in cts:search(/mainDoc, cts:and-query(()), "unfiltered")[49999000 to 5000000]
return base-uri($item)
```

The `cts:and-query(())` is a shortcut way to pass an always-true query.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the second method and it is considerably faster than the queries in my original question.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way to use `cts:uris` would look something like this:

```
subsequence(cts:uris((), 'limit=50000000'), 49999000)
```

It would be even more efficient if you could pass in a start value, but that requires you to know the 49999000th value up-front.

```
cts:uris($start-value, 'limit=1000')
```

See http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris for more about that function.

Comment: Thanks mblakele.  Your subsequence solution was the most performant yet.