# Moving where into cts:search

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts-search

Given this query:

```
for $d in cts:search(
      fn:doc(),
      cts:and-query(
       (            
         cts:collection-query(('InProgress_Audit'))
       )
      ))          
      where not(fn:contains($d//TitleDate/text(),"Z"))
      return <p>{document-uri($d)}</p>
```

How do I move the "where" constraint into the CTS search query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses `cts:query` to apply your constraints:

```
for $d in cts:search(
  fn:doc(),
  cts:and-not-query(            
     cts:collection-query('InProgress_Audit'),
     cts:element-query(xs:QName('TitleDate'),
       cts:word-query('*Z*', 'wildcarded'))
  ))
return <p>{document-uri($d)}</p>
```

There are index options to speed up wildcarded searches. You could also use a range index on `TitleDate` in combination with a `cts:element-range-index-query` to speed this up even further.

**Update:** As @mblakele points out in the comments, `cts:element-value-query` may be faster than the nested `cts:element-query`/`cts:word-query`:

```
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('TitleDate'), '*Z*', 'wildcarded')
```

And using cts:uris will be faster than making many repeated calls to `document-uri()`. However, you would need to enable the URI lexicon option in your settings. Putting all that together, the query would look like:

```
cts:uris((), 'document',
  cts:and-not-query((            
     cts:collection-query('InProgress_Audit'),
     cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('TitleDate'), 
       '*Z*', 'wildcarded')
  ))) ! element p { . }
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but a `cts:element-value-query` may perform better than the nested `cts:element-query` and `cts:word-query`. Also, given the call to `document-uri` it might be even better to use `cts:uris` rather than `cts:search`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17710863/908390 has an example.